# Storing of integer literals when defining variable

Tags: c++, int, literals

If I write such operator:

```
int a=32;
```

Do I properly understand , that integer literal **32** is storing like int number somewhere in code, and then, this constant is assigned to my variable a?

Comment: The compiler creates a literal "32" during compilation, which will eventually be moved to the address specified by `a`.

Comment: You can't make any assumptions, other than the fact the a will be initialised to the value 32 as required.

Comment: Yes! That's what the compiler will usually do.

Comment: It depends, if it's a global variable then the compiler will store `32` directly in the variables place in the data segment. If it's a local variable, then there's some code to initialize it.

Comment: I think you are comparing string literals with constants. `a` is assigned memory location and 32 is copied to it. Integer 32 itself is not stored anywhere unlike string literals.

Comment: @Mahesh Well, that depends on your definition of "stored". It should still be in the binary *somewhere*. As in `mov [esp + 12], 0x20`...

Comment: Without any optimization(!): The compiler might store the value 32 in the program and copy it to the address of a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. `int a` actually means "keep `sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack available and let's call `a` that pace, and fill it with the 32 number.

The `=`, here is not an assignment (`a` does not exist before: it is created as such), but an initializer.

And where the number 32 goes, it depends on the underlying processor and relative instructions. It can even go inside the code itself, with instruction like `LD (DS+a), 32`, where DS is the data-segment pointer, `a` the offset of the `a` variable and 32 just the bit representation in binary of the number 32.

Answer (score 0):

CPU instructions often have a form that holds a literal value; in that case, the store instruction that's generated by `a = 32` contains the value to be stored; in other cases, the value is stored somewhere in program data and copied from there into the variable.

Back in the olden days of FORTRAN, you could pass a constant to a function which modified it, and from then on the constant had the new value. This was not a good thing.